# How to implement a streaming engine so that raspberry Pi video streaming on home network can become public

Tags: python, video-streaming, hole-punching

I have implemented a motion detection + webcam video streaming on raspberry pi using HTTP Threaded server and open CV. Now I want to make it publicly accessible while my pi is on home network. I understand there are three ways to do it:

1. Port Forwarding
2. Reverse tunnelling
3. Using hole punching (what dataplicity and remot3.it does)

I would like to know if there is a simple script which would help achieve 3, ie., what dataplicity does, where in the stream goes to a cloud server, and that cloud server then serves the request.

I'm certain this could be implemented with a very few lines of code, but if a working example could be provided, that would help immensely. Code in any scripting/language is okay. I need to understand also what is it that needs to be taken into consideration when creating this solution.

For my case, I'm concerned about just couple max raspberry pi devices. Also, a max of 1-2 connections would be there so a max total of 4 simultaneous streams are possible, which means if the example code is not sturdy enough for high loads, that is perfectly okay.

Comment: It seems this would do the trick? (A). running a UDP server listening for packets on cloud machine, (B). A client on pi device which keeps on sending the packets to this cloud machine, to be picked up by UDP server. (C) For each device on home network, ie, for each raspberry pi which we want to connect to cloud server, we should use some unique identifier on cloud server, which could then be used to store messages received temporarily against that device in some buffer (D) Run web server on cloud server, and expose an API which takes in device ID and serves data it received via UDP server?

Answer (score 0):

Use autossh on your Raspberry Pi to forward the webcam port to a port on a remote server.  autossh will ensure that the connection stays alive and will re-open it if necessary.

```
sudo apt-get install autossh
```

You can use a free-tier eligible AWS EC2 instance that is assigned a public IP as the remote server.  During creation you will be given a .pem keypair file that you use to connect to the instance.  Upload this file to the Raspberry Pi.

The autossh command would look like:

```
autossh -l ubuntu -N -R 80:localhost:webcamPort serverIP -p 22 -i /path/to/key.pem -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

If using an AWS AMI linux image change the username from 'ubuntu' to 'ec2-user'.

Also you may need to edit the ssh config and enable GatewayPorts on the AWS linux server.  Add the below to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

Once the connection is established you will be able to access it by browsing to http://serverIP/.

Comment: While this may work, in practice, I need to understand how the hole punching would be implementing. Just out of curiosity, how would I be able to connect to multiple camera streaming video on pi?

Comment: This would be reverse tunneling, not hole punching.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work for a good explanation of how it works.  If you wanted to forward multiple streams there are several ways you could do it but the easiest would be to just forward stream #2 to a different port on the server, like port 81.  You'd then have a stream available at http://serverIP/ and http://serverIP:81/